# Is there any country where I can apply for a Schengen visa while being a tourist?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, schengen-visas, india

I am an Indian citizen looking to travel to Germany this summer. However, there is a big shortage of visa appointments across the country and I'm looking for ways to get a Schengen visa.

I was thinking of travelling to a third country near India (like Singapore) and applying for a Schengen visa from there. However, the German embassy in Singapore requires me to have a residence permit (https://singapur.diplo.de/sg-en/service/05-VisaEinreise/-/2455416) while I will just have a tourist visa. Is there any country from where this is possible?

Comment: Would an Indian visa agency be able to expedite the process? This will cost money, but then again, so will travelling to another country to apply for a visa there. That being said, I randomly looked up the embassy in Bangkok and they don't seem to have any residency requirements.

Comment: @Mophotla even if there is no requirement, it will certainly raise a few eyebrows, and you certainly want to avoid raised eyebrows when you ask for a visa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Schengen rules are **designed to assure** that applicants go to the right consulate or embassy of the right country, and not "pick" one which is supposedly "easier" for getting visa. The right consulate is the one where you are resident, with very few exceptions. If you were to spend a couple of months as a tourist abroad, you *might* be able to apply from there, but not on a relatively short trip.